# When i try to insert my notification type object then child entity also tries to insert

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have a notificationTypes table, permission table. these are linked by the help of bridge table notification_types_permission. 
When all the entities are new, it works fine. 
My issue is that when I try to insert new notificationTypes with existing permission, that time permission also tries to insert a new one.
My table and entity structures are given below.

```
 CREATE TABLE `notification_types` (
  `Id` BIGINT(16) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TypeName` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `InsertedDttm` DATETIME NULL,
  `InsertedBy` BIGINT(16) NULL,
  `UpdatedDttm` DATETIME NULL,
  `UpdatedBy` BIGINT(16) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`));

CREATE TABLE `notification_types_permission` (
  `Id` BIGINT(16) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `NotificationTypes_ID` BIGINT(16) NOT NULL,
    `permissions_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`), FOREIGN KEY (NotificationTypes_ID)
        REFERENCES `frontoffice`.notification_types(id), FOREIGN KEY (permission_Id)
        REFERENCES `frontoffice`.`permission`(id));
public class NotificationTypes {

    @Id 
    private Long id;
    private String typeName;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date insertedDttm;
    private Long insertedBy;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updatedDttm;
    private Long updatedBy;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<RLPermissions> permissions;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 private List<RLPermissions> permissions;
```

avoid cascade property from that relationship if there is no need to delete, update and insert operation for permissions list.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the new Permission first:

```
Permission p = permissionDao.getPermissionByName("SuperAdmin");
```

Then add it like this:

```
notificationType.notificationTypesPermission.getPermissions().add(p)
```

Comment: my problem is existing permission also try to add as new one.

Answer (score 0):

you have set cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST which will update the many side of the relationship. Any change to the NotificationTypes will update the corresponding child entities

CascadeType.PERSIST : means that save() or persist() operations cascade to related entities.